# C# application log4net log file not created when used in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++, dll, c++-cli, log4net

I've written a C# dll - foo.dll - that uses log4net for logging. The dll is then used in a C++ application via a C++\CLI wrapper. The C++ application works perfectly, however the **log file is not created**. When I use this dll in a testing C# application (that uses the original C# dll) the log file is create without problems.

This configuration is set in foo.dll.config:

```
  <configSections>    
    <section name="log4net"
      type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="D:\\foo.log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

Other configuration are read without problems from the foo.dll.config file and the C++ application has writing permissions for the log directory.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I re-write my comment as answer.

You must try to define an app.config file for your C++ application (not only for the dll itself), and include on it the log4net configuration.